# Qual expressão regular posso utilizar para remover espaços duplos em Javascript ou PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, regex

Qual expressão regular posso utilizar pra remover excesso de espaço em branco? Quer dizer, deixá-los com a quantidade de espaços normalizados.

Exemplo

De:

```
$string = 'Estou no    Stack   Overflow em Português   ';
```

Para:

```
$string = 'Estou no Stack Overflow em Português';
```

Gostaria de exemplos em PHP e em Javascript.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Se você considerar quebra de linhas, tabs, entre outros como espaços use **`\s`**, caso contrário você pode usar **`( )`** - como no exemplo.

**PHP**

```php
$str = preg_replace('/( )+/', ' ', "stack    overflow");
```

**Javascript**

```js
var str = "stack    overflow".replace(/( )+/g, ' ');
```

---

Sobre a regex:

**`( )`** captura espaços vazios. O **`+`** indica que pegará todas as sentenças (de espaços vazios) subsequentes.

Answer (score 9):

#### Alguns tipos de "`writeSpace`"

```
" " espaço simples - represente o " " espaço
\n - representa a quebra de linha
\r - representa o retorno de carro
\t - representa um tab
\v - representa um tab vertical (nunca vi, nem usei)
\f - representa o avanço de pagina
\s - engloba todos os demais
```

#### Algumas REGEX

```
/ {2,}/      - captura apenas dois ou mais espaços
/\n{2,}/     - captura apenas linhas duplas
/(\r\n){2,}/ - captura apenas linhas duplas, que possuam retorno de carro (alguns editores poem por padrão `\r\n` ao pressionar enter)
```

#### Sua situacao

#### PHP

```
$str = preg_replace('/( ){2,}/', '$1', $str);
```

#### JavaScript

```
str = str.replace(/( ){2,}/g, '$1');
```

#### Explicação

```
( )  - captura um espaço simples e gera um grupo
{2,} - quantifica um no minimo dois ao infinito
$1   - recupera o grupo
```

Comment: Apenas salientando esta `REGEX` sempre substitui vários espaços por um espaço, caso queira deixar sem espaço tanto no inicio como no fim, tanto PHP como JavaScript possuem a função `trim`. ou se quiser posso fazer por `REGEX` também só que é mais complicado e não recomento, já que a função exste.

Answer (score 3):

Dessa forma já resolve:

**Javascript:**

```
var text = 'Estou no    Stack   Overflow em Português   ';
    text = text.replace(/\s+/g, " ");
```

**PHP:**

```
$text = 'Estou no    Stack   Overflow em Português   ';
$text = preg_replace('/\s+/', " ",$text);
```