# Como remover espaços em branco de uma string com RegEx em PHP?

Tags: php, regex

Como seria uma RegEx em PHP para eliminar mais de um espaço em branco de uma *string*?

Por exemplo, `<img src='  smiley. gif'>` gostaria que ficasse `<img src='smiley.gif'>`.

Comment: A pergunta a se fazer é: por que existem espaços no caminho da imagem?

Comment: não tinha lido direito, atualizei a resposta

Comment: Seguindo o pensamento do @AndersonCarlosWoss aconselho vivamente a rever o seu códido e tentar perceber porque é que o `link` da sua imagem contem esses espaços.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Qual expressão regular posso utilizar para remover espaços duplos em Javascript ou PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/81870/qual-express%c3%a3o-regular-posso-utilizar-para-remover-espa%c3%a7os-duplos-em-javascript)

Answer (score 5):

Você pediu RegEx, mas não precisa, se tiver acesso ao conteúdo do atributo pode usar operações de *string* mais eficientes:

```
$com = "'  smiley. gif'";

$sem = str_replace(' ', '', $com);
```

Se tem mais caracteres a substituir, pode por no primeiro parâmetro:

```
// remover espaço, tab e quebra de linha \n

$com = "'  smiley. gif'";

$sem = str_replace(array(' ', "\t", "\n"), '', $com);
```

> Manual https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.str-replace.php

Agora, o ideal mesmo é consertar a origem dos dados para nem precisar disso.

Answer (score 1):

Use o comando ltrim para remover o espaço do inicio e rtrim para remover do fim. Ou apenas trim para remover do final e inicio:

```
echo ltrim("    |ola mundo|");
```

para remover espaço tem o str_replace

```
echo str_replace(" ", "", " ola mundo.jpg");
```

Caso queira um regex:

```
echo preg_replace("/\s+/", "","    ola mundo");
```

Comment: resposta atualizada

Answer (score 1):

A pergunta esta vaga, não dá para saber se a entrada será só uma imagem ou pode ser um HTML com várias imagens, se for o segundo caso então inicialmente você deve preferencialmente manipular o DOM, por exemplo:

```
$myhtml = "
<p>
    <img src='  smiley1. gif'>
    <img src='  smiley2. g if'>
    <img src='  smiley3. gi f'>
    <img src='  smiley4 . gif'>
</p>
";

$doc = new DOMDocument;

//Carrega e interpreta a string
$doc->loadHTML($myhtml, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED|LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);

//Pega todas as imagens dentro do documento
$imgs = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');

//Faz o loop para remover o espaço um a um de cada imagem
foreach ($imgs as $img) {

    //Pega o atributo SRC de cada imagem
    $src = $img->getAttribute('src');

    //Aqui pode usar a solução do Bacco ou do Ricardo
    $src = preg_replace('#\s+#', '', $src);

    //Atualiza o atributo SRC
    $img->setAttribute('src', $src);
}

//Mostra resultado
echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

Note que usei:

- `LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED` previne adicionar as tags html e body
- `LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD` previne adicionar o Doctype

Exemplo online: https://repl.it/@inphinit/remove-spaces-in-src-attributesphp

---

Note que se quiser exibir o HTML sem que ele seja "executado" (interpretado) pelo navegador você deve usar `htmlspecialchars`, exemplo:

```
//Mostra resultado
echo htmlspecialchars( $doc->saveHTML() );
```

Relacionado: [**Qual a diferença entre htmlspecialchars() e htmlentities()?**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/252675/3635)